# How can I format pivot table data as % of Row Totals in R's Openxlsx2 package?

Tags: r, excel, pivot-table, openxlsx

I'm placing a pivot table in a workbook via R package OpenXLSX2. The data default to a format Sum Count. Is there anyway to render the data as a % of ROW Total from R. Here is a code snippet, output and preferred output:

**Code**

```
wb <- wb %>%
  wb_add_pivot_table(df, sheet = 1,dims = "B10", rows = "data_row", cols = "rating", data = "count")
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Preferred Output:**

[image]

One can accomplish this manually with a right click in Excel like this:
[image]

But, I need to find a way to accomplish this programmatically. Is it possible?

Comment: That is [not yet possible](https://github.com/JanMarvin/openxlsx2/pull/833)

Comment: You provided a code that already has the variable wb. We dont have wb in our environment.

Now, I tried it anyway but I achieved a different kind of results (numbers dont matter, only format). is that helpful?

load the `tidyverse` and use this code:

> s <-  table(mtcars$carb,mtcars$gear)[1:4,]
rownames(s) <-   paste0("data_row_",1:nrow(s))
colnames(s) <- c("above","fully","partial")
s
mytab <- addmargins(s,margin = 2)
mytab |> class()

mytab[1,] / mytab[1,4]
map_df(1:4,~mytab[.,] / mytab[.,4]) |> 
  mutate(across(everything(),~scales::percent(.)))

Comment: Thank you @JanMarvin! I love this package. Huge fan. I can solve this problem with VBA for the time being. I see the related work on GitHub.  Keep up the great work!